# How to get page URL when a link is clicked in an email

Tags: javascript, php, html, email, iframe

I need to get the URL of the page. when any link is clicked in an Email body, page URL should get appended to the link.
I tried using javascript and Iframes, but it seems that due to security reasons, email clients disable the use of Iframe and javascript.
I have also tried mailgun webhook but not getting the result as required.
Please suggest an alternative to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just so I understand this correctly... I open an email from your site, in say Gmail, and you want to capture the URL that is in the browser when I click the link? If so you are not really going to be able to do that. You might be able to capture the referrer when the user hits your site, however this would not work when a user is using a client such as Thunderbird or Outlook since they are not on a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

you may also want to get user C: drive content and passwords, but fortunately you cannot do this :) The email doesnt know about the environment where it is open for privacy reasons. Also it doesnt need to be a website obviously, it can be a mobile email client or outlook for example.